# Is possible to someone hack to my computer and stole my data if I using bitLocker encryption?

Tags: windows-7

If I configure BitLocker on my Windows operating system and I encrypt drive D (for data only), not drive C (OS), if my computer gets hacked can the hacker see the content of my D drive?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the attack. If your machine was infected by a Trojan, that takes over the interactive session, then yes they would be able to view and hypothetically transfer your files.

If your machine was stolen and the hard drive removed from the system, the theif would require your credentials to decrypt the files.

Answer (score 0):

6 years later...

Yes, by a brute force attack.

But it takes some time, especially for passwords longer than 8 characters.